# Outlook (O365) REST API (client side)

Tags: sharepoint, office365, office365-apps, office365api, office365-restapi

We are working on solution, that via injected javascript on Sharepoint Online site uses Outlook (O365) 
REST API (client side) and injects entries to the calendar on Sharepoint subsite. 
For that purpose, application on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com has been registered. 
Overall, it’s working quite well, however, there is problem about Redirect URIs on the application itself. 
As site collection contains many subsites with their own calendars, to make it work, we supposed to add 
redirect URIs for all of the particular calendars, what may be difficult, as new sites will be created during site collection lifespan. 
So basically what we would like to achieve, is to add for example “allowed domain” in the application, 
that will allow redirections for the all of the subsites as well.

Is this even possible?
What is best practice?

Regards,

Pawel

Answer (score 0):

Just redirect to a page in your app with all links you would like to include.

Also, keep in mind, using the api will apply security so the user will be able to see only authorized calendar for his identity, so you don't need to include static link that a user may not have access to.

Hope this helps.